# Varnish failing to detect valid probe page

Tags: spring-boot, varnish

Having a problem with Varnish 3.x probe page from a SpringBoot application (1.4). Varnish is failing to detect the probe page (returns 503 SERVICE NOT AVAILABLE) and consequently fails to route.

When I manually ping the probe URL, it works fine, but Varnish is flagging the probe page as being down.

Removing the probe page, everything works fine.

Pointing to a static probe page (my.css) or any other static or dynamic URL fails.

Looking at the logs, the response header looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 72
Date: Wed, 01 Feb 2017 15:20:48 GMT
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Comparing this to other working (non Spring Boot) applications, the only difference is that the working applications have an OK after the response, and the bad ones don't:
     HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Does that mean anything?

For example, here is a good one:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 01 Feb 2017 14:04:18 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 11 Nov 2016 22:00:02 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 129
Server: Jetty(9.3.z-SNAPSHOT)
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Is this a SpringBoot issue? Not sure where else to look!

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Varnish support has replied

You found the issue: https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/issues/2069

This is "fixed" in master. But maybe you can fix your backend?

Now to see how to change Spring Boot response message!